# WebDeploy to deployment slot

Tags: deployment, web-deploy, azure-devops

We are deploying our Sitecore 9.2 app using Azure DevOps. More specifically we use WebDeploy and deployment slots and have noticed the following behaviour:

- deployment to deployment slot takes an extended time (25+ mins), if
  the target slot has a different code-branch deployed
- if we re-deploy to the same slot, without having swapped the target
  slot into production, the following deployment takes a short time(5-8
  mins)
- the majority of the files (all the sitecore files) have not changed
  between deployments

We can see that when our deployment takes a short time, there are few files updated and when deployment takes a long time, all the files (9000+) are updated. We are puzzled by the fact, that the Sitecore files are updated, since they are the only thing that does not change.

We have tried using webdeploy with -usechecksum parameter and without, but it does not result in any noticeable difference.

We also tried to deploy the application, without using deployment slots and that is always fast (5-7 mins).

Here is a screenshot of our deployment step: (Azure App Service deploy task v.4)
[image]

Is there a way to constantly achieve quick deployment times and use deployment slots?

Comment: Can you post your msdeploy command in full?

Comment: @MarkGibbons Added screenshot of deployment step in full

Comment: You can turn of the slot before deploying, this will make it really fast

Answer (score 1):

Have you confirmed you have 'ignore app_data' checked? You don't want to Web Deploy sync over that folder if you can avoid it as Azure puts hundreds of meta files into folders in there which would then all be removed and it can take quite some time...

If you deploy once and it takes ages, but then re-deploy and it's quicker it could just be that there are fewer of Azure's files to be removed with web deploy on the 2nd deployment?

Comment: I can confirm that I have enabled "Exclude files from the AppData folder". Also, I am wondering why Webdeploy wants to update my Sitecore files since they are not changed between deployments

Comment: @Hos I think if you've got a new package, it's likely the file time stamps will be different and that's what web deploy uses by default to identify changes to files. This is a pretty decent description of how to configure things if this is your issue: https://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/06/03/webdeploymsdeploy-quick-tip-only-deploy-changed-files/